# Finding the basis of a vector subspace of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let V be a vector $\mathbb{R}$-space of all continuous $f(x)$ of one real variable defined on $[0,2]$. And let W denote the set of all $f(x) \in V$ s.t. the degree of $f(x) \lt 3, \: f(1)=0$.

Show that W is a vector subspace of V and find a basis and the $dim(W)$. We need to satisfy the conditions $\alpha f(x) \in W, \: \forall f(x) \in W$, which is straightforward since scalars will not change the degree of the polynomial and $\alpha f(1) = \alpha 0 = 0$, and that $f(x)+g(x) \in W, \: \forall f(x),g(x) \in W$. Let $f(x) = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma$ and $g(x) = \mu x^2 + \lambda x + \delta$, then $f(x) + g(x) = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma +  \mu x^2 + \lambda x + \delta = (\alpha + \mu)x^2 + (\beta + \lambda)x + (\gamma + \delta) \in W$. Hence W is a vector subspace of V.

**How do I go about finding the basis of W?**

Also if I define V as an inner product space with $\big<f(x),g(x)\big>=\int_0^2 f(x)g(x)dx$, how do I find an orthonormal basis of W and the projection of $h(x)=2x^3-4x+1$ onto subspace W?

Comment: you said in your first paragraph that $V$ is the vector space of all continuous functions of one variable in $\mathbb{R}$ on the interval $[0,2]$, and W is a subspace of all $f(x)$ with degree $< 3$.  So is it W just polynomials or are $V$ and $W$ both the V.S of real polynomials?  I assume it's just $W$, considering $V$ is over the interval $[0,2]$.

Comment: What is the dimension?  Assuming your vector space W is the space of all polynomials of degree at most 2, what do  you think a standard basis might look like?  How many different "variables" / powers of a variable do you need to create at most a quadratic polynomial?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $W$ is meant to be the space of *polynomials* of degree at most 2, and with a root at 1.  Is that right?

To find a basis, consider the fundamental theorem of algebra.  The elements of $W$ must all have $(x-1)$ as a factor.  Consider the monomial $u=(x-1)$, and construct a basis from there that is analogous to the usual basis (which would be an excellent basis for constructing the space of polynomials with a root at zero).

---

For your second question, once you have found a basis, you just use the Gramm-Schmidt process. Just remember that the projection of $\mathbf{v}$ onto the one dimensional vector space spanned by the unit vector $\mathbf{u}$ is just $$\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle \mathbf{u}$$ 
The vector $$\mathbf{v}'=\mathbf{v}-\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle \mathbf{u}$$ (often called the *error term*) is therefore orthogonal to $\mathbf{u}$, so $\{\mathbf{v}',\mathbf{u}\}$ is an orthogonal basis for the space $\textrm{Span}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})$.

To project $\mathbf{w}$ onto the two dimensional space $\textrm{Span}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})$, just take the sum of the projections of $\mathbf{w}$ onto the orthogonal basis vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$.

Comment: So our basis for W is {$1,x,x^2$} with dimension 3?

Comment: No.  But if we let $W'$ be the set of polynomials of degree at most $2$ and with a root at $0$, then the set $\{x,x^2\}$ is a basis for $W'$.

Comment: I don't really understand how the "root at 0" comes into play?

Comment: OK, let's stick to $W'$ for now.  We can move back to the original problem, and $W$ later.  A polynomial $f$ has a root at $0$ if $f(0)=0$.  According to the fundamental theorem of algebra, this is equivalent to having $x$ (or $(x-0)$, if you prefer) as a factor. This is obvious when you consider the $y$-intercept: $ax^2+bx+c$ has a root at $0$ just in the case that $c=0$.  More generally, if our basis functions are $x^{0}, x^{1},x^{2},\ldots$, then it is obvious that the space $W'$ has $\{x^{1},x^{2}\}$ as a basis.

Comment: So what you're saying is that since $f(1)=0$ all elements of W must have $(x-1)$ as a factor, so a basis for W is {$(x-1)^1,(x-1)^2$}.

Comment: That is correct.